# Work Bench throwing errors still on going

Tags: workbench

Work bench has been giving this error for a week now, I see many others are experiencing the same issue. Looking for a update or any new information. UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379

Answer (score 0):

Hi [RickOSasktel](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/135370/rickosasktel),

I got the same trouble, I found fake solution about revoking your name on connected Apps on stackexchange, but it didn't work for me.
I'm desperately looking for a solution but I keep finding posts mentioning the same problem or posts about how Workbench isn't supported by SF officialy which I already know but it doesn't help...

AN ACTUAL SOLUTION is :
Use the Heroku App instead : https://foxworkbench.herokuapp.com/